# Prevent Class from filling with empty values

Tags: php, upload

I wrote a upload script on my site where users can upload a predefined number of items (12 in my case). A user can edit his project (of course...).
So I also wrote an update-script. Project are read from the database and a user can reupload or delete certain files. But what I have write know is, when a users doesn't upload a new file, the original file is overwritten by an empty value (makes sense, since the `<input>` is empty.
But I want to prevent that. How do I do this?

**Form**:

```
$activities = Project::getProjectById($_DB, $projectnumber);
if(!empty($activities)) {
    foreach($activities as $k => $v) {
        echo "<input type='text' value='".$v['name']."' name = 'newproject_name' />";
        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= 12) {
        if(!empty($v["photo$i"])) {
           echo "<img src='../files/".$v["photo$i"]."' width='200' height='200'  />";
           echo "<input type='file' name='images[]' />";
        }   
        $i++;
        }
     }
     echo "<input type=submit value='Update' name='submitted'>";
     echo "</form>"; 
}
```

**PHP**:

```
$project = new Project();
$project->name      = $_POST['newproject_name'];

$project->photo1    = $_FILES['images']['name'][0];
$project->photo2    = $_FILES['images']['name'][1];
$project->photo3    = $_FILES['images']['name'][2];
$project->photo4    = $_FILES['images']['name'][3];
$project->photo5    = $_FILES['images']['name'][4];
$project->photo6    = $_FILES['images']['name'][5];
$project->photo7    = $_FILES['images']['name'][6];
$project->photo8    = $_FILES['images']['name'][7];
$project->photo9    = $_FILES['images']['name'][8];
$project->photo10   = $_FILES['images']['name'][9];
$project->photo11   = $_FILES['images']['name'][10];
$project->photo12   = $_FILES['images']['name'][11];

if($project->updateProject($_DB, $projectnummer)) {
   $feedback = "<div class='feedback good'>ok!!</div>";
} else {
   $feedback = "<div class='feedback bad'>NOT ok!</div>";
}
```

You don't have to worry about the `getProjectById` and `updateProject`-function, they work just fine. But as you can see, the script will upload all the empty values and overwrite them in the database...
I would like to prevent that! Any advice?

**EDIT**:

```
 if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][0])) {
        $project->photo1    = $_FILES['images']['name'][0];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][1])) {
    $project->photo2    = $_FILES['images']['name'][1];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][2])) {
    $project->photo3    = $_FILES['images']['name'][2];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][3])) {
    $project->photo4    = $_FILES['images']['name'][3];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][4])) {
    $project->photo5    = $_FILES['images']['name'][4];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][5])) {
    $project->photo6    = $_FILES['images']['name'][5];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][6])) {
    $project->photo7    = $_FILES['images']['name'][6];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][7])) {
    $project->photo8    = $_FILES['images']['name'][7];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][8])) {
    $project->photo9    = $_FILES['images']['name'][8];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][9])) {
    $project->photo10   = $_FILES['images']['name'][9];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][10])) {
    $project->photo11   = $_FILES['images']['name'][10];
  }
  if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][11])) {
    $project->photo12   = $_FILES['images']['name'][11];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$project->photo1    = $_FILES['images']['name'][0];
$project->photo2    = $_FILES['images']['name'][1];
$project->photo3    = $_FILES['images']['name'][2];
$project->photo4    = $_FILES['images']['name'][3];
$project->photo5    = $_FILES['images']['name'][4];
$project->photo6    = $_FILES['images']['name'][5];
$project->photo7    = $_FILES['images']['name'][6];
$project->photo8    = $_FILES['images']['name'][7];
$project->photo9    = $_FILES['images']['name'][8];
$project->photo10   = $_FILES['images']['name'][9];
$project->photo11   = $_FILES['images']['name'][10];
$project->photo12   = $_FILES['images']['name'][11];
```

can be rewriten as

```
for ($i = 0; $i <=11; $i++) {
    $photo = 'photo' . ($i + 1);
    $project->$photo   = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
}
```

And you can resume all your edit with:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <=11; $i++) {
    $photo = 'photo' . ($i + 1);
    if ( ! empty($_FILES['images']['name'][$i])) {
        $project->$photo = $_FILES['images']['name'][$1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Some clever code, thanks! However, I get a parse error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /customers/9/1/7/***.php on line 64`, Are you sure I can use a variable when declaring a Class?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375873/php-class-property-chaining-in-variable-variables

Comment: Ok, for some reason the `!empty`-part isn't working... It's still uploading the empty values and replacing the strings in the database with empty ones...

Comment: In http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php Class properties may also be accessed using variable property names. The variable property name will be resolved within the scope from which the call is made. For instance, if you have an expression such as $foo->$bar, then the local scope will be examined for $bar and its value will be used as the name of the property of $foo. This is also true if $bar is an array access.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You should use `is_uploaded_file()` function ([LINK](http://www.php.net/is_uploaded_file))?

**EDIT:**

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++) {
  if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['name'][$i]))
     $project->photo[$i] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
}
```

Comment: It's quite similar to `file_exists`, no? What I want is to upload only the new files and keep the already uploaded files...

Comment: Maybe You could check file size and name (if the same, then don't upload).

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but the form is also passing by the empty values. And that's what I want to prevent!

Comment: So check every value with with `is_uploaded_file` function. If it's returning `TRUE`, check the other parameters of particular file (like size and name) for checking if file was uploaded earlier. If not, then upload :).

Comment: Ok, right :-) Then I get something like you can see in my edit. There must be an easier way to do this... With far less code, no?

Comment: Ok, for some reason the `!empty`-part isn't working... It's still uploading the empty values and replacing the strings in the database with empty ones...

Comment: That's why i used `is_uploaded_file` :)

Comment: Right :), and is there a reason why you `if` function isn't using any `{}`?

Comment: and the `is_uploaded_file` also results in an empty database... The existing values are being overwritten by empty ones...

Comment: If we use only one line of code in `if`, then we can use it without `{}` :). `is_uploaded_file` function checks if file was uploaded, if not, then it's returning FALSE. Database should be overwritten, when this function returns TRUE.